# Typescript - React and NextJS + NextAuth with custom server

Tags: node.js, typescript, next.js, next-auth, fastify

I'm building a NextJS application with NextAuth to manage authentication session, I'm also using a custom server written in typescript and using FastifyJS.

It works well except for NextAuth configuration: I have created a custom login page and when I go to the login page I got the error:

```bash
- error unhandledRejection: Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: No "exports" main defined in /Users/lorenzocolautti/Desktop/WORKSPACE/GitHub/certifie.info/node_modules/@auth/mongodb-adapter/package.json
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:393:5)
    at throwExportsNotFound (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:358:9)
    at packageExportsResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:612:7)
    at resolveExports (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:529:36)
    at Function.Module._findPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:569:31)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:27)
    at Function.call (/Users/lorenzocolautti/Desktop/WORKSPACE/GitHub/certifie.info/node_modules/@cspotcode/source-map-support/source-map-support.js:811:30)
    at /Users/lorenzocolautti/Desktop/WORKSPACE/GitHub/certifie.info/node_modules/next/src/server/require-hook.ts:116:34
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:841:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1061:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
    at /Users/lorenzocolautti/Desktop/WORKSPACE/GitHub/certifie.info/.next/server/pages/api/auth/[...nextauth].js:112:15
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  digest: undefined
}
```

I use mongodb and I cannont find solutions on the web.

The strange thing is that when I start the NextJS application without custom server (`next dev`), the login page works well without errors.

What is the problem with custom server and the package `@auth/mongodb-adapter`?

The following are the `tsconfig.json` (ts configuration) and the `tsconfig.server.json` (ts configuration for the custom server):

tsconfig.json

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "removeComments": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "incremental": true,
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./*"]
    }
  },
  "ts-node": {
    "transpileOnly": true,
    "compilerOptions": {
      "module": "commonjs"
    }
  },
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

tsconfig.server.json

```json
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": ".next",
    "target": "es2017",
    "isolatedModules": false,
    "noEmit": false
  },
  "include": ["server.ts", "types/*.ts"]
}
```

could the problem depends by how the `tsconfig.server.json` is configured? Maybe `target` or `module` configuration?

The following the `server.ts` file:

```js
import fastify, {
  FastifyBaseLogger,
  FastifyInstance,
  FastifyPluginOptions,
  FastifyReply,
  FastifyRequest,
  FastifyServerOptions,
} from 'fastify';
import fastifyCron from 'fastify-cron';
import fastifyStatic from '@fastify/static';
import fastifyCookie from '@fastify/cookie';
import fastifyCors from '@fastify/cors';
import { Server } from 'http';
import Next from 'next';
import { parse } from 'url';
import path from 'path';
import os from 'os';
import { environment } from './classes/application';
import { TaskController } from './classes/abstracts/task-controller';
import "./tasks/_index"; //register all tasks

const dev: boolean = !environment.isProduction;
const isDeployedOnServer: boolean = environment.isDeployedOnServer;
const port: number = environment.port;
let host: string = environment.hostname;
if (dev && !isDeployedOnServer) {
  const net = os.networkInterfaces();
  host = (net?.eth0 || [{}])[0].address || host;
}

const options: FastifyServerOptions<Server, FastifyBaseLogger> = {
  logger: { level: 'error' },
  pluginTimeout: 0,
};

const public_path = path.join(__dirname, '../public');
fastify(options)
  .register(fastifyStatic, {
    root: public_path,
    prefix: '/public',
    list: true,
  })
  .register(fastifyCookie, {
    secret: 'my-secret',
    parseOptions: {},
  })
  /*.register(fastifyCors, {
      origin: (value: string | undefined, cb: Function) => {
          let origin: boolean = true;
          if (value) {
              const hostname = new URL(value).hostname
              if (hostname === "localhost") {
                  origin = false
              }
          }

          cb(null, { origin })
      }
  })*/
  .register(
    (
      server: FastifyInstance,
      opts: FastifyPluginOptions,
      next: Function
    ): void => {
      const app = Next({ dev });
      const handle = app.getRequestHandler();
      app.prepare()
        .then(() => {
          server.all("/", async (req: FastifyRequest, reply: FastifyReply): Promise<void> => {
            const parsedUrl = parse(req.url, true);
            req.raw["application"] = { environment: environment, url: req.url };

            reply.redirect("/welcome");
          });

          server.all("/*", async (req: FastifyRequest, reply: FastifyReply): Promise<void> => {
            const parsedUrl = parse(req.url, true);
            req.raw["application"] = { environment: environment, url: req.url };

            return handle(req.raw, reply.raw, parsedUrl)
              .then(() => reply.hijack());
          });

          server.setNotFoundHandler(async (req: FastifyRequest, reply: FastifyReply): Promise<unknown> => {
            return app.render404(req.raw, reply.raw)
              .then(() => reply.hijack());
          });

          next();
        })
        .catch((err: any) => next(err));
    }
  )
  .register(fastifyCron, { jobs: TaskController.tasks })
  .listen({ port, host }, (error: any, address: string) => {
    if (error) {
      console.error(error);
      throw error;
    }

    console.log(`hostname ${host}`);
    console.log(`port ${port}`);
    console.log(`⚡️ listening on ${address}`);
    console.log(``, JSON.stringify(environment, null, 4));
  });
```

EDIT: I forgot to share the `[...nextauth].ts` file:

```js
import NextAuth, { Account, AuthOptions, CallbacksOptions, Profile, Session, Theme, User } from 'next-auth'
import { AdapterUser } from 'next-auth/adapters'
import { MongoDBAdapter } from "@auth/mongodb-adapter"
import { JWT } from 'next-auth/jwt'
import EmailProvider from 'next-auth/providers/email'
import clientPromise, { Mongo } from '@/classes/helpers/mongo'
import { CompanyDataModel } from '@/classes/data-model/company-data-model'
import { ICompany } from '@/classes/interfaces/models/i-company'
import { USER_TYPE } from '@/classes/enums/user-type'
import { createTransport } from "nodemailer"
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next'

export const authOptions: AuthOptions = {
    providers: [
        // Passwordless / email sign in
        EmailProvider({
            server: {
                host: process.env.EMAIL_SERVER_HOST,
                port: process.env.EMAIL_SERVER_PORT,
                auth: {
                    user: process.env.EMAIL_SERVER_USER,
                    pass: process.env.EMAIL_SERVER_PASSWORD
                }
            },
            from: process.env.EMAIL_FROM,
            async sendVerificationRequest(params) {
                const { identifier, url, provider, theme } = params
                const { host } = new URL(url)

                // NOTE: You are not required to use `nodemailer`, use whatever you want.
                let transport = createTransport(provider.server)
                if (["dev", "development"].indexOf(process.env.NODE_ENV) > -1) {
                    transport = createTransport({
                        host: "0.0.0.0",
                        port: 1025,
                        ignoreTLS: true,
                        auth: {
                            user: process.env.EMAIL_SERVER_USER,
                            pass: process.env.EMAIL_SERVER_PASSWORD
                        }
                    })
                }

                const result = await transport.sendMail({
                    to: identifier,
                    from: provider.from,
                    subject: `Sign in to ${host}`,
                    text: await text({ url, host }),
                    html: await html({ url, host, theme }),
                })

                const failed = result.rejected.concat(result.pending).filter(Boolean)
                if (failed.length) {
                    throw new Error(`Email(s) (${failed.join(", ")}) could not be sent`)
                }
            },
        }),
    ],
    session: {
        strategy: "jwt",
        maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60,
    },
    pages: {
        signIn: '/app/auth/login',
        verifyRequest: '/app/auth/verify-request',
        error: '/app/auth/error',
    },
    adapter: MongoDBAdapter(clientPromise, {
        databaseName: process.env.MONGODB_NAME, collections: {
            Users: "auth-user",
            Accounts: "auth-account",
            Sessions: "auth-session",
            VerificationTokens: "auth-verification-token",
        }
    }),
    secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
} as AuthOptions

/**
* Email HTML body
* Insert invisible space into domains from being turned into a hyperlink by email
* clients like Outlook and Apple mail, as this is confusing because it seems
* like they are supposed to click on it to sign in.
*
* @note We don't add the email address to avoid needing to escape it, if you do, remember to sanitize it!
*/
async function html(params: { url: string; host: string; theme: Theme }) {
    const { url, host, theme } = params

    const escapedHost = host.replace(/\./g, "&#8203;.")

    const brandColor = theme.brandColor || "#346df1"
    const color = {
        background: "#f9f9f9",
        text: "#444",
        mainBackground: "#fff",
        buttonBackground: brandColor,
        buttonBorder: brandColor,
        buttonText: theme.buttonText || "#fff",
    }

    return `
          <body style="background: ${color.background};">
            <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="20" cellpadding="0"
              style="background: ${color.mainBackground}; max-width: 600px; margin: auto; border-radius: 10px;">
              <tr>
                <td align="center"
                  style="padding: 10px 0px; font-size: 22px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: ${color.text};">
                  Sign in to <strong>${escapedHost}</strong>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td align="center" style="padding: 20px 0;">
                  <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <tr>
                      <td align="center" style="border-radius: 5px;" bgcolor="${color.buttonBackground}"><a href="${url}"
                          target="_blank"
                          style="font-size: 18px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: ${color.buttonText}; text-decoration: none; border-radius: 5px; padding: 10px 20px; border: 1px solid ${color.buttonBorder}; display: inline-block; font-weight: bold;">Sign
                          in</a></td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td align="center"
                  style="padding: 0px 0px 10px 0px; font-size: 16px; line-height: 22px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: ${color.text};">
                  If you did not request this email you can safely ignore it.
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </body>
          `
}

/** Email Text body (fallback for email clients that don't render HTML, e.g. feature phones) */
async function text({ url, host }: { url: string; host: string }) {
    return `Sign in to ${host}\n${url}\n\n`
}

export default async function auth(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
    authOptions.callbacks = {
        async signIn({ user, account, email }: {
            user: User | AdapterUser, account: Account | null, email?: {
                verificationRequest?: boolean | undefined;
            }
        }) {
            let isOk: boolean = true;
            const auth: { type: USER_TYPE } = JSON.parse(req.cookies.auth_user_parameters || "{}")
            if (auth?.type == USER_TYPE.corporate) {
                const model: CompanyDataModel = new CompanyDataModel();
                const company: ICompany | null = await model.get_by_user(user?.email)
                    .catch(() => null);
                console.log(company)

                isOk = !!company;
            }

            return isOk;
        },
        async jwt({ token, account, user }: { token: JWT, account: Account, user: User | AdapterUser }) {
            // Persist the OAuth access_token to the token right after signin
            if (account) {
                token.accessToken = account.access_token
            }
            if (user) {
                token.role = user.role;
            }
            return token
        },
        async session({ session, token, user }: { session: Session, token: JWT, user: AdapterUser }) {
            // Send properties to the client, like an access_token from a provider
            if (token && session.user) {
                session.user.role = token.role;
            }

            session.accessToken = token.accessToken

            return session
        }
    } as Partial<CallbacksOptions<Profile, Account>>;

    return await NextAuth(req, res, authOptions);
}
```

Thanks you very much for your help, I really don't know what is the problem.

Comment: LGTM. Did you try to reinstall? For example, followed `rm -rf node_modules`, `rm -f package-lock.json`, `rm -f yarn.lock`, `npm cache clean --force`, and `npm i` these steps?

Comment: @GolamrabbiAzad yes, I did it several times. I changed `@auth/mongodb-adapter` with `@next-auth/mongodb-adapter` package, the backend does not print errors in console anymore but next-auth continue to not working (I click to signin but nothing happens)... if I run `next dev` (so without custom server), the application works well.

Comment: I was looking at your error info. The error shows from the `[[...next-auth]].ts` file. There might be an error in the file caused by the `@auth/mongodb-adapter` library or other factors. And did you read the next.js docs about the custom server to integrate with next.js?

Comment: Yes, the documentation does't speak about nextjs and next-auth integration with custom server. I decided to have 2 applications, one of them is the web application in nextjs and the second one is the cron-based application. I wanted to use the custom server to set up Fastify and set up cron with the same app configuration to the web application.